# install JRE in heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, shared-libraries

I got this error in running **heroku run rake sunspot:solr:run**

```
rake aborted!
You need a Java Runtime Environment to run the Solr server
```

is there a way i can install jre in heroku?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot install the JRE on Heroku, and thus you cannot run Solr from a Heroku worker.

If you want Solr in Heroku, you'll have to use the [Websolr](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/websolr) addon, or start an EC2 server and run your own copy of Solr from there.

Comment: Doesn't Heroku offer JVM-based languages now?

Comment: sad to hear. though i tried running my own server for solr, it didnt work. maybe because of the reindexing issues.